# How to update name and views of a perforce client

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

Is there a way to update the ***name and views*** of an existing perforce client from **command line** instead of creating a new client(copying views from old client) and deleting old client ?

I know you can do this like

```
p4 client -t old_client new_client | p4 client -i
```

but that is copying views from `old_client` and creating `new_client` instead of updating `old_client`

Comment: No way to rename a workspace I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks @Matt for the confirmation. I can use the same command mentioned above but was wondering if it is the correct way. It seems to be the only way.

Comment: If your goal is to just rename a client and you don't want to have to resync all of the files let me know and I'll post the command cocktail.